# How to generate closed curve?

Tags: beziers, curves

How can I do that? I can generate simple beziers, but how can I generate a closed curve like this:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=endscreen&NR=1&v=hlDYJNEiYvU

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just Google `closed bezier curve`, there are plenty of useful results, including [one that has a code example](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33776/Draw-Closed-Smooth-Curve-with-Bezier-Spline) It's just like a open bezier curve, but for the "next" point on your last point, you use the first point.

Comment: This code example is doing something that has no sense. You can't just equate second derivatives of two parametric curves because their parameters are not related. It's like equating miles and nanometers.